# Is there a way to handle redis timeouts and not to fail the API if redis is unavailable

Tags: java, redis, reactive, spring-data-redis

For my API , I am using redis cache , sometimes while calling redis we get exceptions like timeout because of which the API fails even though the data is present in redis and in database.
Is there any way that if redis fails then my API does not stop working and we get the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually manually configure redis by creating a redis properties class with the @Configuration annotation above the class. You can then set a variable of type Integer for the timeout (whether it be in ms, s, or even minutes). After that class is created, in your application properties, you can set this timeout variable to any number you wish so that redis does not timeout.

Comment: So according to this if in the given time frame connection is not established, redis will not throw timeout exception?

Comment: It will throw an exception but you can always increase the time until the connection is made. Else, even if redis has the data, you'll never be able to attain it.